# Yielding multiple items at once in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

How can I yield multiple items at the same time? I am scraping a list of URLs where each of these URLs has about 10-20 nested URLS.  I scrape each nested URL for 10 items of information that I need to yield.  Is there a way to yield 10 items at the same time?  Maybe through a list or something that I append each item to then yield them all at the end?  I am not totally sure how to do this.  Any suggestions?

Example of Code:

```py
class OdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'od'
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = ["url1, url2, . . . . ."]

    def parse(self, response):
        # scrape nested urls
        yield scrapy.Request(nested_url, callback=self.parsenestedgame)

    def parsenestedgame(self, response):
        i1 = item1()
        i2 = item2()
        # 9 other items then adding info to items
        yield item1(**i1)
        yield item2(**i2)
        # how can I yield all of these items at the same time?
```

Comment: Why do you need to yield the items **at the same time?** I think what you want is just to yield several items in a single parse method, but since you mention at the same time I'm not sure. Or maybe they all should be a single item?

Comment: @renatodvc I have other spiders that scrape for only one item type so they only have to yield one at a time. This website is an aggregator website that has 11 types of these items in one place. I'm just wondering the best way to send these 11 types of items through the item pipeline for each of the nested urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured it out I just appended all of the items to a list like:

`item_list.append(item1(**i1))` . . . .etc

Then I iterated over the items like:

```
for item in item_list:
    yield item
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the the information provided in the comments:

You can have any number of Items and yield them as soom as you populate each of them, in whatever order you want. Since the `yield` statement doesn't terminate the code execution they can even follow each other as you presented in your sample code.

They will all reach the ItemPipelines and there you can make the distinction and treat them differently if you need.

If that doen't answer your question I may have not fully understood it. Please explain what you are trying to achieve and what you tried and didn't work, so I can be more helpful.

Comment: When I run my code it only ever sends the i1 to the item pipeline the others never are sent.